# Access Additional Exchange Mailbox using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: interop, outlook, exchange-server

I'm trying  to find a way using the Office.Interop.Outlook COM object to connect to an additional Mailbox.  Currently I am doing the following (after adding the COM object):

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon();
var inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

This successfully connects me to my main Inbox which I can then loop through.

What I am trying to find next is a way to use additional Mailbox X and get the default folder.

I am using Framework 4.0 with the COM object Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library (version 9.3)

Not sure on the version of Exchange.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have it :-

```
ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon();
var recipient = ns.CreateRecipient("xx@yy.com");
recipient.Resolve();
var sharedFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

Not sure if the `ns.Logon` is necessary, but I have left it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Luke has the correct answer above. The following code works for Python 3.7 using pywin32:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

other_user = outlook.CreateRecipient("user.name@example.com")
print(other_user)
other_mailbox = outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(other_user, 6) # 6= inbox see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.oldefaultfolders?view=outlook-pia
print(other_mailbox)
print(other_mailbox.Items[0])
```