# Specify shared inbox during PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

How does one specify a shared email account during a PowerShell script?  I'm trying to get metadata from a shared email account using this code (designed for a default email account):

```
   Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

function Get-MailFromOutlookFolder
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Object] $ParentFolder
    )

    $items = @()

    foreach ($folder in $ParentFolder.Folders)
    {
        foreach ($item in ($folder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Items"))
        { 
            if ($item.Class -eq 43)
            {
                # process email
                $items += $item | Select-Object -Property "ConversationTopic", "ReceivedTime", @{ "Label" = "Folder"; "Expression" = { $_.Parent.Name } }
            }
        }

        # process (sub)folder items
        $items += Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $folder
    }

    return $items    
}

$outlook     = New-Object -Com "Outlook.Application"
$mapi        = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
$results = Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $mailboxRoot
$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\email.csv"
```

I've made four attempts to solve this problem:

1.

`$mailboxRoot = $mapi.Folder(1).Parent`

(In place of the line `$mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent`)

Error code: `Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass] does not contain a method named 'GetFolder'.`

2. Based on the info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130310/change-directory-in-powershell).

`Set-Location -Path 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\<emailaddressOfSharedAccount>'`

Error code: `Set-Location : Cannot find path`  (Path definitely exists).

3. Based on the info [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/read-emails-from-a-shared-account-in-outlook/a6b6a23a-520a-4e80-af4a-1add38fdf108?page=3).

`Set FldrIn = FldrInbox.Folders("C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\<sharedInboxEmailAddress>.ost")`

Error code:`Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'FldrInbox.Folders'.`

4. Based on the info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.namespaceclass.getshareddefaultfolder?view=outlook-pia#microsoft-office-interop-outlook-namespaceclass-getshareddefaultfolder(microsoft-office-interop-outlook-recipient-microsoft-office-interop-outlook-oldefaultfolders)).

`GetSharedDefaultFolder (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient Recipient, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders FolderType)`

Error code: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient : The term 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Update:
It seems like I need to update the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467928/access-additional-exchange-mailbox-using-microsoft-office-interop-outlook).

Comment: What is it you're trying to do exactly? Can you share your script?

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I clarified the script above and my goal.

Comment: oops - yes the variable was missing.

Answer (score 0):

This variable is not being declared:

> $mailboxRoot

This should resolve it:

```
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a shared inbox, you need to replace the line `$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent` with `$mapi.Folders.Item(3)`.  Just keeping changing the number in the parenthesis till you hit your desired shared inbox.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

function Get-MailFromOutlookFolder
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Object] $ParentFolder
    )

    $items = @()

    foreach ($folder in $ParentFolder.Folders)
    {
        foreach ($item in ($folder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Items"))
        { 
            if ($item.Class -eq 43)
            {
                # process email
                $items += $item | Select-Object -Property "ConversationTopic", "ReceivedTime", @{ "Label" = "Folder"; "Expression" = { $_.Parent.Name } }
            }
        }

        # process (sub)folder items
        $items += Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $folder
    }

    return $items    
}




$outlook     = New-Object -Com "Outlook.Application"
$mapi        = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.Folders.Item(3)
$results = Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $mailboxRoot
$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\email.csv"
```

Comment: If you know the name of the shared mailbox you just need to filter result. The $map.Folders object has a property called "Name". Just do a Where-Object to filter out the rest of the mailboxes.

Comment: If you put your map.folder/where-object code as an answer, I'll vote it up - it's much smarter than my approach of just randomly putting in numbers ;-)